# Jenkins Build with Active Choices Plugin Hangs

Tags: jenkins, build, build-process, jenkins-plugins

It seems that every project I build with Active Choices Plug-in got hanged whether the build is successful or not.

The following is the configuration of the Multi-configuration project

[image]

I add 1 active choices parameter

[image]

then I asks jenkins to execute "echo Hello".

When I build the project, what I see on the screen is:

[image]

Jenkins keeps staying in this state until I click on the blue circle button.

After clicking on the blue circle, I see:

[image]

Anyone knows why my build hangs?

I wish Jenkins could show me console output directly.

My Jenkins version is 1.634, and my Active Choices Plug-in version is 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by "ENABLE AUTO REFRESH".